# How to check JOOQ array type field is empty

Tags: kotlin, jooq, r2dbc

Given there is Postgres array type, how to assemble where condition to check if it is empty.

I have tried to use the following clause, it did not work as expected.

```kotlin
 where = if (arrayExists== true) {
    where.and(DSL.length(USERS.ACCOUNT_IDS.name).greaterThan(0))
 } else {
    where.and(DSL.length(USERS.ACCOUNT_IDS.name).equal(0))
 }
```

NOTE: arrayExists is an external parameters from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, jOOQ supports the `CARDINALITY()` function via [`DSL.cardinality(Field<? extends Object[]>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#cardinality(org.jooq.Field)). It's what you'd write in PostgreSQL and standard SQL as well:

```sql
select cardinality(array[1, 2])
```

Producing

```
|cardinality|
|-----------|
|2          |
```

Comment: It seems `PostgresDSL` includes an  `arrayLength` method for this purpose.

Comment: When the array field is not set, use `PostgresDSL.arrayLength` in where can not return the correct result. I have to use `cardinality` here.

Comment: @Hantsy: Hmm, not sure what the problem is here? A subtle difference of behaviour between the two PG functions? Or a bug in jOOQ? (In the latter case: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose)

Comment: In my case, I added a new record into table without setting the array field, query the table whit where `PostgresDSL.arrayLength(field).eq(0)` return empty list, but using `cardinality`  get a list with the exact record.

Comment: Update my personal project to reproduce this issue, and filed an issue on Jooq project, https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14047

Comment: @Hantsy: Thanks for the bug report. As mentioned on there, I recommend you use `cardinality()`, which produces a more straightforward result for empty arrays